# Is it possible that Job's wife and children were not actually taken from him, but that it was actually a fabrication to discourage him?

Tags: context, job

Job 1

> 18 While he was yet speaking, there came also another [messenger] and said, “Thy
> sons and thy daughters were eating and drinking wine in their eldest
> brother’s house, 19 and behold, there came a great wind from the
> wilderness and smote the four corners of the house, and it fell upon
> the young men, and they are dead; and I only have escaped alone to
> tell thee!”

Job was told his wife and children had died, but no evidence was ever produced, that I know of.

His wife appeared to be present at the end of the story, and not all his children were stipulated to have been born later. She may not have needed to return.

Comment: Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for joining the group.  Please remember to take the tour (link bottom left) to better understand how this site is different.

Comment: Is there a specific text you wish to consider that could be interpreted this way?  This appears to be inviting unfounded speculation.

Comment: I took the liberty of editing the OP so it includes the report that Job received about his children. I think this is a "teaching opportunity" so there's really no need to close the post. I agree it calls for speculation.

Answer (score 0):

First, let's clarify the facts: Job was not told that his wife had died. So we do not need to deal with with the issue of how she came to be present at the end of the story.

As to whether the story of his children dying could be a fabrication by the messenger (or the messenger's boss), there is nothing in the text that even hints at it. On the other hand, some scholars do see both the prolog and the epilog of Job as being written by another author than the main text. If so, the prolog could be a fabrication designed to explain how God came to allow the innocent Job to suffer so badly. The ending could be the ancient equivalent of a Disney ending to an unhappy Grimm's fairy tale, where everyone lives happily ever after.

The [Yale Bible Study](https://yalebiblestudy.org/courses/wisdom-literature/lessons/job-prologue-study-guide/) puts it in terms of an earlier fable being incorporated into the a later dialog:

> Most scholars assume that the
> prose frame [the epilogue and prologue] reflects an older folktale, in which Job was consistently
> patient. In the book as we have it, however, the introductory story
> sets up a problem but does not resolve it. Moreover, the epilogue does
> not quite match the introduction, since it is concerned with the
> friends rather than with Satan. The traditional story, then, is
> adapted for its present context. It is not simply reproduced.

**Conclusion**:  Job's children dying and the account of his being given new children at the end of the book may both be "fabrications" in the sense that they are  fanciful stories written by a different author than the dialog sections of the book. But there is no indication of a fabrication involving the messengers who brought Job the news. [The OP is mistaken in its assertion that Job was told his wife had died.] The dialogue and God's answer to Job stand as masterpieces of sacred literature, whether one thinks that the prolog and the "fairy tale" epilog are fabrications or not.

Answer (score 0):

People tend to interpret these events in different ways, but the fact remains that the text itself indicates Job’s children did die. The reasons for this are:

- **Credible messengers:** The messengers who brought the news of the tragedies were credible sources within the narrative. They were not
  portrayed as deceitful or unreliable characters. Job
  1:13-19
- **Specific details:** The text describes specific details about the circumstances of their deaths, such as the collapse of the house due
  to a great wind, which lends authenticity to the account.
  Job 1:18-19
- **Job's reactions:** Job's reactions to the news, including his mourning and tearing of his robe, indicate genuine grief and loss. Job 1:20-22
- **Interactions with his wife:** Job's subsequent interactions with his wife, where she advises him to curse God and die, suggest that
  she indeed experienced the loss of their children and is grappling
  with her own grief and despair. Job 2:9-10
- **Subsequent children:** Later in the narrative, after Job's restoration, it mentions that he had additional children, implying
  that his original offspring had indeed perished. Job 42:13-15

The text does not say that Job's wife died. Now, the Book of Job is a complex text that deals with heavy topics such as suffering, faith and divine sovereignty. However, the simple and most straightforward answer is that Job’s children died in a tragic accident, rather than being fabricated to discourage him.

Comment: In which chapter/verse does it say Job's wife died?